# Using jQueryMoblie and phonegap in Android

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I use phonegap and jQueryMoblie in android, when I run the program, it cannon use the phonegap function but it can show jQueryMoblie behavior:

`<a href="gps.html"><input type="button" value="GPS" /></a>`

another case, i can run the function but cannot show jQueryMoblie behavior:

`<input type="button" value="Camera" onclick="document.location.href='gps.html'" />`

how can i use both function in the program?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, this should work for you:

```
 <a href="gps.html" data-role="button">Camera</a>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First I don`t really get the point of your question. But I just trying to to help, or you can be more specific :D. Are you sure you have added phonegap.js in your project? As far as I know to make phonegap API working, you have to add phonegap.js in your html page. Then you can access hardware through phonegap API.